# How to differentiate between normal and admin user in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm fairly new to MVC and Laravel 8 and I have added the User Register / Login by running the related Auth commands and Laravel added users database and Register and Login pages accordingly. All works well.

After this, I added a user_type field in migrations an enum field with the user and admin and then I created an AdminController and its separate view, all is working fine when I do /admin I get the admin view and I also added the route and secured it so that user has to log in before they can view the admin.

The only issue I'm facing is that any user who has logged in is able to view admin. How can I restrict so that users with user_type = 'admin' can only view the admin area?

Right now I am doing a hack by adding the following code at top of the admin layout view:

```
    @if (Auth::user()->user_type != "admin")
        <script>
            window.location = "./";
        </script>
    @endif
```

This works but it's a hack and if anyone with javascript disabled will be able to get in.

P.S: I am manually setting the user_type field of a user to 'admin' in PHPMyAdmin.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simples solution is to move the check in your route action e.g. `if (Auth::user()->user_type != "admin") { return redirect()->to('/'); }` however a more complete solution is to use [authorisation to write gates or policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization)

Comment: You can create a middleware and restrict in web routes. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Comment: Both of the above comments are good takes, I want to add that there are various role-permission libraries for laravel you could add. They do all of the above work for you and you can simply use their methods, middlewares etc.

Answer (score 3):

Many possibilities for Authentication and Authorization.

1. Passport Package `composer require laravel/passport`
2. Spite Package `composer require spatie/laravel-permission`
3. [Policies](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-gates-and-policies-tutorial-with-exampleexample.html)
4. Custom Middleware

and many more but that's are famous in market

Comment: Could you provide a link for each of them, and perhaps a sentence of explanation on how each of these options solve/approach the problem?